# Nuxtjs use component vue-pano

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I used [vue-pano](https://github.com/ChiChou/vue-pano) with [Nuxtjs](https://fr.nuxtjs.org/)
I have this error : "window is undefined"

if I import like this:

```js
<script>
import Pano from 'vue-pano'

export default {
  components: {
    Pano
  }
}
</script>
```

So I used a plugin:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'

if (process.browser) {
  Vue.component('Pano', require('vue-pano'))
}
```

But I have error :

> [Vue warn]: The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching
>   server-rendered content. This is likely caused by incorrect HTML
>   markup, for example nesting block-level elements inside `<p>`, or
>   missing `<tbody>`. Bailing hydration and performing full client-side
>   render.
>
> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: `<pano>` - did you register the
>   component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide
>   the "name" option.

How can I install vue-pano with nuxtjs ?

Thank you!

Comment: I think it is a problem with `Pano`, they probably don't precompile the templates when releasing a dist. If so, the solution would be to open an issue in their repo and ask them to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to use any vue plugin that makes use of window or document, you need to wrap them in a `<no-ssr></no-ssr>` component (provided by nuxt).

With

> if (process.browser) {
>    Vue.component('Pano', require('vue-pano'))
>   }

you are registering globally the component if the context is browser. But what you would like to do isntead is to import it only in browser mode:

```
const noSSRComponents = {};

if (process.browser) {
    const vuePano = require('vue-pano');
    noSSRComponents.vuePano = vuePano;
}
export default {
// ...
    components: {
        ...noSSRComponents,
    }
}
```